# Raster multiplication

Tags: raster, pyqgis

My script should multiplicates the pixel value of a raster, but produce a raster with only 0.

```
import os
import os.path
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry

rasterVH_filepath = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/divisione/VH1/VH1.tif"
output = "/home/giacomo/Desktop/divisione/out/prova.tif"

entries = []

myLayer1 = QgsRasterLayer(rasterVH_filepath, 'raster')
my1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
my1.ref = 'my@1'
my1.raster = myLayer1
my1.bandNumber = 1
entries.append( my1 )

calc = QgsRasterCalculator('my1@1 * 10', 
output,
'GTiff',
myLayer1.extent(),
myLayer1.width(),
myLayer1.height(),
entries)

calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: Dear German it works, but I don't know why. Thank you very much anyway

Comment: Just posted the comment as an answer, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the name you are giving to your raster:

```
my1.ref = 'my@1'
```

is the same name you use in your expression:

```
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('my1@1 * 10', ... # This will fail
```

So, just change `my1@1` by `my@1` in your expression:

```
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('my@1 * 10', ... # This will work!
```